# Add Shape at the end of the document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to add a shape specifically a textbox.

I need to add it after all the contents I added through vba. I can't seem to figure how to do it since adding the shape needs the exact measurement of the Left and Top parameters.

```
Dim shpActual 
Dim pos, PtsToInches 
set shpActual = Selection.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 92, PtsToInches, 437.4, 69) 
pos = Selection.Range.Informatio(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) 
PtsToInches = pos / 72
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.RelativeVerticalPosition` to position the shape after you insert the shape. See this example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim objShape As Shape

    Set objShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox _
    (Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=10, Top:=10, Width:=80, Height:=80)

    With objShape
        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionColumn
        .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionBottomMarginArea
        .Left = wdShapeCenter
        .Top = wdShapeTop
    End With
End Sub
```

**Followup**

One other way is to find the cursor position and then insert the shape at that position. For example this will insert a shape where the cursor is. So in your original VBA code, you can use `Selection.TypeParagraph` to move to the next line and then call the below code.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim objShape As Shape
    Dim pos, PtsToInches

    Set objShape = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox _
    (Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=10, Top:=10, Width:=80, Height:=80)

    pos = Selection.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)

    PtsToInches = pos / 72

    With objShape
        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionColumn
        .Left = wdShapeCenter
        .Top = PtsToInches
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! But the document's number of pages varies. The shape was placed at the end of the first page only.

Comment: It's not working .. :( It says 'Type mismatch in 'Set objsShape' line. I tried to declare objShape without a type but now the error occurs in 'Object doesn't support this property or method.' in 'pos = Selection.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)'

Comment: I tested the code before posting. Can you share the code that you tried.

Comment: Dim shpActual Dim pos, PtsToInches set shpActual = Selection.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 92, PtsToInches, 437.4, 69) pos = Selection.Range.Informatio(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) PtsToInches = pos / 72