# How do I find the location of text in Word 2010?

Tags: vba, textbox, ms-word

I'm writing some VBA in Word 2010 to generate a text box and position it adjacent to the start of a paragraph, like a highlight in the margin.  So basically I'll highlight the first phrase of a paragraph, run the macro and the box will be generated, aligned with the text.

The problem is specifying the vertical location for the text box.  I was hoping that I can get a 'Top' property from a highlighted section of text, but there's nothing that looks useful in the ActiveDocument or Selection objects.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Thanks

Comment: See if this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395929/add-shape-at-the-end-of-the-document/14396350#14396350

Comment: Thank you Siddharth, yes that gave me the insight I needed.  Appreciate your time!